# What Squarespace JSON variables are available in the backend CMS email templates?

Tags: json, squarespace, jsontemplate

I have a site with Squarespace. Squarespace allows you to send different confirmation emails for each type of product using:

```
{.section hasPhysicalProduct}
{.section hasServiceProduct}
{.section hasDigitalProduct}
```

What I'd like to do is send different confirmation emails based on the quantity of a product that the customer orders. I'm sure there must be a variable for this somewhere, similar to

```
{order.submittedOn}
```

But Squarespace doesn't reveal these variables even in its [Tag Quick Reference](http://developers.squarespace.com/quick-reference). I've taken a few guesses (order.quantity, order.itemCount) without luck. Does anyone know where to find a list of these JSON variables for a site like Squarespace?

Answer (score 1):

In the backend Squarespace CMS you're seeing a very controlled JSON environment with regards to these "templates". They're not documented because there aren't that many JSON variables available. I've tried nearly everything and there isn't much available outside of the defaults.

Comment: So the Tag Quick Reference is all that's out there? Have you found anything that organizes what is offered any better or is SS the only one that presents it?